# Applying class to all occurence of a word

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the JS file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:contains('Fail')").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Fail", "<span class='red'>Fail</span>"));
    });
    $(".title").html(function(i,v){
        return v.replace("Pass","<span class='red'>Pass</span>");
    });
});
```

and HTML:

```
 <div class='title'>
     <table border="1" class="dataframe">
         ....
         .....
         <td>Pass</td>
         <td>0.55</td>
         <td>Pass</td>
         <td>Pass</td>
      </table>
  </div>
```

When I run this 'red' class is applied only to first occurrence of both pass and fail. How do I apply it to all occurrence of it in `div` tag.

Comment: Use regular expression to replace and use with `/Pass/g` instead of `"Pass"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use regular expression replace with [global match modifier `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:contains('Fail')").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Fail/g, "<span class='red'>Fail</span>"));
    });
    $(".title").html(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace(/Pass/g, "<span class='green'>Pass</span>");
    });
});
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
.green {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>
    <table border="1" class="dataframe">
        <td>Pass</td>
        <td>0.55</td>
        <td>Fail</td>
        <td>Pass</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

By the way, it makes sense to use something like `green` class for "Pass", like I did in the demo above.